# Error when updating the Record Routing list

Tags: 2007, error, records-management

I'm updating the Record Routing list to indicate that a new record type will be routed in certain document library. As per [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/add-records-to-the-record-routing-list-HA010174283.aspx), in step 6, I have to update the Aliases box to add the record types, seperating them with forward slash ('/'). However, I got this error

> The record routing name or location cannot contain: \  **/** : * ? " # % < >
>   { } |, two consecutive periods (..), or special characters such as a tab.

However, the documentation says I have to supply '/' to separate the records type.

*Strange :-S*

How to I update the Record Routing list without causing this error?

**Update 1**

I ran the folloiwng PowerShell script

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Policy")

function Get-SPWeb([string]$url) {
    $SPSite = Get-SPSite $url
    return $SPSite.OpenWeb()
    $SPSite.Dispose()
}

function Get-SPSite([string]$url) {
    New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "sp web url"

$recSeries = New-Object Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.RecordSeriesCollection -ArgumentList $web

$entry = $recSeries.Item(6) # 6 just happens to be the entry I wanted to edit

# add new record routing rules by adding a new item base opn existing one.
# The RecordSeriesCollection has no means to update entry, nor does RecordSeries
$recSeries.Add(
    $entry.Name + "and Forms",
    $entry.Location,
    $entry.Description,

    $entry.Mappings + @("Record Type 1", "Record Type 2"),
    $entry.Router,
    $entry.Default
)
```

And I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my answer, after three months of searching.

In my case, the error isn't caused by the entries in the Alias field, but rather by the illegal entry in the Location, which has a colon ":" in it. After further investigating the issue, it appears that the Location field will not accept the Display name of the document library, but the "actual"[1] name should be used instead. For an example, when I create a document library named "Client: Reports", the actual name is "Client Report". SP appears to remove the colon in the actual name.

Moreover, if the display name is changed, the actual name has to be used.

For my case, I was using something like "Client: All Documents" but the actual name is "AllDocs".

**NOTE:**

1. I'm not sure if this is the technical name of this particular property of the Document library. This actual name is the one found in the url, for my case it's `<sp site>/AllDocs/Forms/<view-page>`.